# Use SSD for OS and HDD as main storage

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

So most people get a SSD to put their OS on to make it run faster, and I figured I'd do it too. Now when I want to use any programs from my old HDD, such as Malwarebytes, games, ventrilo, etc., I get issues like missing dll's or access issues. I think I've cleared any access problems, but my question is this:

How can I run my OS off my SSD, and all my other programs off my HDD without these issues?

I have seen a few things about moving the Users folder over and that may fix things. I also don't want to reinstall everything, if at all possible I just want to keep running everything from what's already on the HDD. The SSD can support a lot of stuff, its a 240gb, but I still want to only put certain things on and leave everything that doesn't require super speed on the HDD.

Comment: Did you format your HDD and SSD before installing windows?

Comment: I did for the SSD, which is new enough that another format would not kill me if required. The HDD came with it years ago when I bought it so I imagine they did.

Comment: *it* being my computer in general, sorry for vagueness

Comment: How did you install windows onto the SSD? and did you install these software packages after you installed windows on the SSD?

Comment: I downloaded an ISO from microsoft, burned it onto my flash drive with Windows 7 USB DVD Download Tool, and installed from the usb. Anything else on the SSD was downloaded after that.

Comment: Was the software packages on you HDD installed before or after this install?

Comment: The HDD had everything installed prior to installing Windows on the SSD. It has been my main storage for years, and everything runs smoothly when I boot from the HDD

Comment: Simple answer, all your registry entries - hard coded information in installed files, ect.... are not setup for your new install - easiest solution uninstall and re-install everything

Comment: I was hoping there was a way to avoid that. It's just a huge pain to basically completely reinstall my computer to get a faster boot time. Well if this is the only way, it will work if I install to the HDD while running from the SSD, correct?

Comment: Yes correct easiest way to test is to just try it with one application to confirm it will work

Answer (score 1):

You added the SSD with Windows (let's assume C:) and 'moved the HDD over' which previously contained all your programs (let's assume this is now D:). This won't work. When you install programs all kinds of information (registry entries, DLLs) is inserted into Windows. That information is now 'somewhere' on your D: drive and Windows does not know it.

I guess an old Windows installation is also on your D: drive, as is your data.
Too put it bluntly, your system is now a mess.

Reinstalling everything is indeed a pain, but you made the wrong decision earlier, and you'll have to fix it somehow.

Your best bet is to (re-)install your software all on C: and remove any remnants of it from D:, leaving D: only for your data. Your C: is indeed large enough, you're not telling how large D: is.

Then while working, you can 'manually' remove everything from D: that is not data, so gradually cleaning up your D: drive. Do that in two steps: when you think a folder is no longer required, rename it from *folder* to *folder.removed*, then in a later stage when everything still works, actually remove it.

Note 1: If you start reinstalling software to D: you won't be able to do that cleanup (distinguish old garbage from new installs).

Note 2: Leaving all data on D: gives your an opportunity to have a good backup stategy **and** in the future will make transistions like this easier. Forget using your user directory ('Documents and settings'...) for data.

Note 3: Should you want to use part of C: for data (that needs to be accessed often), put it all under a folder C:\DATA.